# What is the carrying capacity of a large pouch?

Tags: adnd-1e, encumbrance

What is the carrying capacity of a large pouch, small pouch, backpack and so on?

*FAQ:*

- Am I actually playing AD&D 1e: yes
- Have I read the rulebooks: yes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The last page of the *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons Player Character Record Sheets* accessory (TSR Stock # 9028) includes the following table:

**Container       Volume       G.P. Equivalent**
Small pouch         1/4 cu. ft.         25 g.p.
Large pouch         1/2 cu. ft.         50 g.p.
Small sack            1 cu. ft.             100 g.p.
Backpack              3 cu. ft.             300 g.p.
Large sack             4 cu. ft.             400 g.p.

Since the *Players Handbook* already lists other, much smaller numbers for the actual encumbrance of the containers themselves, the implication is that the G.P. Equivalent values are for the containers when fully loaded.

Also, these numbers match the encumbrance example given on page 225 of the DMG, which describes dividing 700 gp amongst 1 large and 3 small sacks.

Comment: I think he divided 700 GP amonsts 1 Large and 3 small sacks: *Dimwall can carry 400 gold pieces in his large sack and another 300 gold pieces in his small sacks*

Comment: Your table is shockingly neat for having been constructed with `&nbsp;` (my congratulations as well as my condolences, since that must have been such a pain), so I wouldn’t want to touch it without asking first, but a LaTeX-based table would be cleaner to edit and the usual preferred method of handling tabular data. I would be happy to convert it for you. Would you like me to?

Comment: Knock yourself out! Haven't embedded LaTeX here before, so this was the best I could do on short notice.